# Show alert() when submit data is duplicate by ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

i have form and jquery. i'll submit form by ajax .

```js
 
                
            $("form#form").submit(function (event) { //submit nama pihak vendor
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

              //validation in here if duplicate
              
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php', //case:"insert_barang_in"
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data == 0){
                            alert('failed');
                        }else{
                            alert("success");
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form id='form'>
    <select name='model[]'>
      <option value=''></option>
      <option value='model-a'>model-a</option>
      <option value='model-b'>model-b</option>
      <option value='model-c'>model-c</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <select name='model[]'>
      <option value=''></option>
      <option value='model-a'>model-a</option>
      <option value='model-b'>model-b</option>
      <option value='model-c'>model-c</option>
      </select>
<br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form
  
  
  </body>
```

how to show alert before data submiting to file.php if value of `name='model[]'` is same ? the alert must in tag `//validation in here if duplicate` .

## its dummy text for pass question, don't read it

Comment: What **should** I read?

Comment: I am Added My Snippet Check Once Its Working Fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form id='form'>
    <select name='model[]' id='model1'>
      <option value=''></option>
      <option value='model-a'>model-a</option>
      <option value='model-b'>model-b</option>
      <option value='model-c'>model-c</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <select name='model[]' id="model2">
      <option value=''></option>
      <option value='model-a'>model-a</option>
      <option value='model-b'>model-b</option>
      <option value='model-c'>model-c</option>
      </select>
<br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>


  </body>


$("form#form").submit(function (event) { //submit nama pihak vendor
       var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        event.preventDefault();
        var model1 = $("#model1").val();
        var model2 = $("#model2").val();

      //validation in here if duplicate
       var flag = 0;
       if (model1 == model2) { flag++; }
      if (flag > 0) { 
        alert("Duplicate"); 
       } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php', //case:"insert_barang_in"
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data == 0){
                    alert('failed');
                }else{
                    alert("success");
                }
            }
        });
      }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan : IT will work,  Check the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lt1aj14z/6/

Comment: not work guys, couse the `selectbox` not just two. it more than two, maybe  the `selectbox` more five because i used `clone()` please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt1aj14z/8/)

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan: I will work. Now check the fiddle link :https://jsfiddle.net/Lt1aj14z/12/

Comment: please use condition like it : select `selectbox` one `model-a` selected, select `selectbox` two `model-b` selected, select `selectbox` three `model-b` selected . its no show an alert, its must show an alert because more than one `model` that same.

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan : Now check it fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt1aj14z/18/

Comment: Yeah, Lakhan very well. its useful. thanks so much. give u ++

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```js
$("form#form").submit(function (event) { //submit nama pihak vendor
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

              //validation in here if duplicate
              
                $.ajax({
                    
                    url: 'vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php', //case:"insert_barang_in"
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data == 0){
                            alert('failed');
                        }else{
                            alert("success");
                        }
                    }
                });
                alert('Before');
                return false;
                ;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form id='form'>
    <select name='model[]'>
      <option value=''></option>
      <option value='model-a'>model-a</option>
      <option value='model-b'>model-b</option>
      <option value='model-c'>model-c</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <select name='model[]'>
      <option value=''></option>
      <option value='model-a'>model-a</option>
      <option value='model-b'>model-b</option>
      <option value='model-c'>model-c</option>
      </select>
<br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form
  
  
  </body>
```

Comment: the validate must be it : if `model-a` in selectbox 1 selected and selectbox 2 `model-a` selected too, it show alert. else that no show alert

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: not work guys, couse the selectbox not just two. it more than two, maybe the selectbox more five because i used clone() please see  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt1aj14z/8/)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment in @Samudrala Ramu answer: please use below code.

If the value in all combo box are same `isAllSame` function will return true else it will return false.

```js
function isAllSame()
{

   var model=document.getElementsByName("model[]");
   for(var i = 1; i < model.length; i++)
   {
      if(model[i].value !== model[0].value)
        return false;
   }
   return true;
}

$("form#form").submit(function (event) { //submit nama pihak vendor
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

           if(isAllSame())
           {
              alert(" All Selected value are same");
              return false;
           }
          //validation in here if duplicate
          
            $.ajax({
                url: 'vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php', //case:"insert_barang_in"
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data == 0){
                        alert('failed');
                    }else{
                        alert("success");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='form'>
    <select name='model[]'>
      <option value=''></option>
      <option value='model-a'>model-a</option>
      <option value='model-b'>model-b</option>
      <option value='model-c'>model-c</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <select name='model[]'>
      <option value=''></option>
      <option value='model-a'>model-a</option>
      <option value='model-b'>model-b</option>
      <option value='model-c'>model-c</option>
      </select>
<br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: code on above work, but the `selectbox` in my script used jquery `clone()` . so, many `selectbox`. not just two . and would you give me jquery only

Comment: so you have multiple model[]?

Comment: if you have 3 selectbox(or any number) and if the value in all 3 are same then prompt alert?( i mean prompt alert only if all selectbox having same value?)

Comment: i just updated answer. please check it will work for any number of combobox

Comment: If you want to use Jquery in function use  var model=$("[name='model[]']");

Comment: not work guys, couse the `selectbox` not just two. it more than two, maybe  the `selectbox` more five because i used `clone()` please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt1aj14z/8/)

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan include `var model = $("#form select[name='model[]']");` instead of `var model = $("input[name=model]");`

Comment: thanks Kumkanillam, please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt1aj14z/9/) !. if i clone `selectbox` to be three and `selectbox` one `model-b` selected, `selectbox` two `model-b` selected, and `selectbox` three `model-a` selected .its no show alert. its should be show the alert, couse if there are two or more `model` same should be show alert .